# Next function doesn't work for Magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magnific-popup

I have tried to apply Magnific Popup to a content gallery. 
Each link will open an individual popup from different gallery.
However, I bump into this issue that when the popup open, I click Next and all popups disappear. Meanwhile, if I click Previous, it still loads the previous popup.

Here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbDwJ

How can I fix the Next function here?

Comment: I suggest you check the error console

Comment: Sorry, I still can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the plugin is having a hard time with the index being a string, you should cast it to an integer:

```
var index=parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'),10);
```

Here's the **[updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybhvk)**